# How include the new facebook SDK in a IOS project ?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have to include directly file from src folder in my project? 
Or i can use the .bundle file ? in this case what i have to do exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steb by step installation instructions can be found from the [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) page

Comment: what if I am using SVN? How can I commit to the source control "the installation" of the project so other programmers who update the code will retrieve it automatically? how does it know where the .m files are?